# Nested If and For Inside If not working VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm got error: "end if without block if" on the last `End If`

This is part of my code:

```
If valorMagnitud > 10 Then

    For Each Sheet In Worksheets
        If textoCodigo.Value = Sheet.Name Then
            GoTo continue
        Else
            ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect Password:="pAtRiCiA"
            Worksheets("Definición").Unprotect Password:="pAtRiCiA"
            Worksheets("Definición").Copy Before:=Sheets("Seguimiento")
            Worksheets("Definición (2)").Name = textoCodigo.Value
        End If
    Exit For

continue:
    Set ws3 = Worksheets(textoCodigo.Value)

    With ws3
        .ListObjects(1).Name = "infoRiesgo" & textoCodigo.Value
        .ListObjects(2).Name = "planesAccion" & textoCodigo.Value
        .Cells(1, 2) = "Definición Planes de Acción " & textoCodigo.Value
        .Cells(5, 5) = textoCodigo.Value
        .Cells(5, 6) = textoResponsable.Value
        .Cells(5, 7) = textoDescripcion.Value
        .Cells(5, 8) = textoControles.Value
        .Cells(5, 9) = textoFrecuencia.Value
        .Cells(5, 10) = textoImpacto.Value
        Select Case valorMagnitud
            Case Is >= 15
                .Cells(5, 11) = "Extremo"
            Case 8 To 14
                .Cells(5, 11) = "Alto"
            Case 4 To 7
                .Cells(5, 11) = "Medio"
            Case 1 To 3
                .Cells(5, 11) = "Aceptable"
        End Select

        Worksheets(textoCodigo.Value).Protect Password:="pAtRiCiA", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
        .Visible = xlSheetHidden
        '.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    End With

    Worksheets("Definición").Protect Password:="pAtRiCiA", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True

    With ws4
        .Unprotect Password:="pAtRiCiA"
        .Cells(.Range("Planes").Rows.Count + 2, 1) = textoCodigo.Value
        .Protect Password:="pAtRiCiA", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
    End With

    ActiveWorkbook.Protect Password:="pAtRiCiA", Structure:=True, Windows:=False

    Worksheets("Valoración").Activate
End If
```

Comment: Your missing `Next` from `For Each Sheet`

Comment: `Exit For` should be `Next`.  (And `GoTo continue` could be `Exit For`, thus avoiding the need for a label.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is caused by the use of `Exit For` instead of `Next`.

---

However ... the part of your code which says

```
For Each Sheet In Worksheets
    If textoCodigo.Value = Sheet.Name Then
        GoTo continue
    Else
        ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect Password:="pAtRiCiA"
        Worksheets("Definición").Unprotect Password:="pAtRiCiA"
        Worksheets("Definición").Copy Before:=Sheets("Seguimiento")
        Worksheets("Definición (2)").Name = textoCodigo.Value
    End If
Exit For
```

isn't going to do what you think it is going to do.

Unless the first worksheet in the workbook has a name equal the the value of `textoCodigo`, your code is going to make a copy of the "Definición" sheet, and attempt to name it with the value of `textoCodigo` - even if that sheet already exists (as perhaps the second, or third, or fourth, etc, sheet) in the workbook.

I think you are trying to create the sheet only if it doesn't already exist.  If so, a minimal change to your code might be:

```
Dim sheetExists As Boolean
sheetExists = False
For Each Sheet In Worksheets
    If textoCodigo.Value = Sheet.Name Then
        sheetExists = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next
If Not sheetExists Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect Password:="pAtRiCiA"
    Worksheets("Definición").Unprotect Password:="pAtRiCiA"
    Worksheets("Definición").Copy Before:=Sheets("Seguimiento")
    Worksheets("Definición (2)").Name = textoCodigo.Value
End If
```